# how to fix the error in telerik report viewer object not found

Tags: sql-server, telerik, blazor-server-side, telerik-reporting

I am using telerik report viewer ,blazor server side and trying to show data from Microsoft SQL sever database data in the report viewer but when i use the shared connection method in Telerik standalone report designer it gives me error in web page that the table is not found where as when i do embedded in report it works fine any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solve this problem by using the string build in the Telerik standalone designer . I just copy that string from there and paste it in the appsetting.json file where my database connection is setup an it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).